# How do I disable the maximum rings cutscene?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

Sometimes when I max out my ring counter, the game will be interrupted by cutscene showing Sonic powering up. Is there a way to disable the max rings cutscene?

Answer (score 1):

Outside modding the game there is only one way... but you aren't going to like it.

Upgrade your speed to max level.
One level at time.
Listening to the dialogue every single time.

Once you do that, the cutscene should not trigger anymore. Unless it is actually a bug.

PS: you **may** need to max the ring count too, but... well, let's just say that for obvious reasons you are going to max that before maxing your speed... so it is a little hard to check...